Does this correctly describe how Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem is proved?
One encounters in books and YouTube videos various ways of describing Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems and their proof. My background is not at all in formal logic, and I want to check if my understanding below of how one can break down the idea of the proof of Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem is (roughly) correct:

Given a formal system $X$, write

$W_X$ for the set of well-formed formulae,
$P_X \subset W_X$ for the set of provable well-formed formulae,
$\neg : W_X \to W_X$ for the negation function.

Theorem: Every sufficiently powerful consistent formal system $X$ has undecidable statements.
Idea of the proof:

We have a function $\,\phi : W_X \to W_X$ [where $\phi(\mathbf{w})$ formalises the statement that $\mathbf{w} \in P_X$] with the property that $\,\phi^{-1}(P_X)=P_X$.
Construct a formula $\mathbf{w}_0 \in W_X$ such that $\,\phi(\mathbf{w}_0)=\neg\mathbf{w}_0$.
Suppose $\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$; i.e. (by 1) $\mathbf{w}_0 \in \phi^{-1}(P_X)$, so $\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) \in P_X$, i.e. (by 2) $\neg\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$, contradicting the consistency of $X$.
Suppose $\neg\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$; i.e. (by 2) $\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) \in P_X$, so $\mathbf{w}_0 \in \phi^{-1}(P_X)$, i.e. (by 1) $\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$, contradicting the consistency of $X$.



If a proof of Godel's 1st doesn't go through his diagonalization lemma, then they are probably proving one of the popular but incorrect characterizations of his theorem.  I recall this https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#:~:text=The%20first%20incompleteness%20theorem%20states,disproved%20in%20%5C(F%5C). being accurate although it tends to present some statements unnecessarily unreadably in FOL when it would have been better to just write them out naturally and show separately that it could be written in FOL.

@DanielV Thanks; I would guess that diagonalization is what is used to achieve step 2? Or is my four-point structure fundamentally incorrect?

It's great that you're interested in logic! I think the hand-waving around $\pi$ is not quite accurate (it's a bit hard to say as it's so hand-wavy!). The first time I saw the first incompleteness theorem properly proved, it was actually just the theorem "PA is incomplete". I think that form is a bit easier to understand. In that scenario, "true" means "this formula is true in the structure $\Bbb N$". So $\pi$ is a function from the set of sentences of $\mathsf{PA}$ to ${\text{true, false}}$ (and is far from injective).

My two cents (based on my own experience of being interested in logic and reading lots of popular presentations before formally learning more about it) is that to really grasp the incompleteness theorems, one should have some technical understanding of the syntax and semantics of first-order logic - for example you should be comfortable with the precise meaning of $\vdash$ and $\models$, and the completeness theorem first. That should be covered in any introductory text or set of notes on mathematical logic.

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you for your very useful comment; in view of what you said about the handwaviness of $\pi$, I have given another shot, which does not fundamentally rely on such a handwavy object. [The non-injectivity of my previous $\pi$ would probably translate into my new $\phi$ being a multivalued function, but I don't want to worry about this in my new formulation - I just want to know if the essence of the logic of my described strategy is correct.]



We have a function $\,\phi : W_X \to W_X$ [where $\phi(\mathbf{w})$ formalises the statement that $\mathbf{w} \in P_X$] with the property that $\,\phi^{-1}(P_X)=P_X$.


We'd usually write this function as $\varphi\mapsto\operatorname{Prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner).$ The property means $\operatorname{Prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ is provable if and only if $\varphi$ is provable. Note that in slight contradiction with your statement of the theorem, this is a statement about both the strength and soundness of the theory... not just consistency. The theory must be strong in the sense that it proves all sentences are provable that are and must be sound in the sense that it doesn't prove any statements to be provable that aren't.


Construct a formula $\mathbf{w}_0 \in W_X$ such that $\,\phi(\mathbf{w}_0)=\neg\mathbf{w}_0$.


This is the diagonalization step. Equality is generally too much to ask for, though. What we really want is for the theory to prove the equivalence: $\operatorname{Prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)\iff \lnot \varphi$ for some $\varphi.$


Suppose $\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$; i.e. (by 1) $\mathbf{w}_0 \in \phi^{-1}(P_X)$, so $\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) \in P_X$, i.e. (by 2) $\neg\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$, contradicting the consistency of $X$.


In other words, if $\varphi$ is provable, then $\operatorname{Prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ is provable by 1 so by the provable equivalence in 2, $\lnot \varphi$ is provable and the system is inconsistent. Yep, that's right


Suppose $\neg\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$; i.e. (by 2) $\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) \in P_X$, so $\mathbf{w}_0 \in \phi^{-1}(P_X)$, i.e. (by 1) $\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$, contradicting the consistency of $X$.


Yes, if $\lnot \varphi$ is provable, then by the equivalence $\operatorname{Prov}(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$ is provable, so by 1, $\varphi$ is provable and the system is inconsistent.

So, yeah, this doesn't seem too far off as a high-level understanding. But note there is a lot glossed over involving constructing the provability predicate (part 1) and proving the diagonal lemma (for which the existence of the sentence constructed part 2 is a special case). The first part is technical but mostly straightforward and unsurprising so seems suitable to omit, whereas the diagonal lemma part seems worthy of further engagement if you want to really have a (rough) understanding the theorem.
Also, as I remarked below part 1, your assumptions in

Theorem: Every sufficiently powerful consistent formal system $X$ has undecidable statements.

are a bit incongruent with the proof sketch here. The direction of part 1 you used in part 4 assumes soundness, not just consistency of the system. Soundness assumptions are, to a certain extent, unavoidable in this version of the proof, though they can be sharpened somewhat (to an assumption of $\omega$-consistency or 1-soundness) and there are other proofs that work with just consistency alone.
Also, perhaps more imporantly, we need to stipulate that the theory is computably axiomatizable, if that is not already implicit in the definition of "formal system". This is necessary for step 1, to make expressing provability in arithmetic possible.

Thank you very much! I understood that the implication $\phi(\mathbf{w})\in P_X \ \Longrightarrow \ \mathbf{w}\in P_X$ does not follow from consistency, but I imagined that in any "sufficiently powerful" formal system there would be a way to get from a proof of $\phi(\mathbf{w})$ to a proof of $\mathbf{w}$. So this is not true?

If we do assume this "soundness", then regarding point 2: you're saying that rather than "$\phi(\mathbf{w}_0)=\neg\mathbf{w}_0$", a more accurate version would be "$\big(
\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) ,\Leftrightarrow, \neg\mathbf{w}_0 \big) \in P_X$", from which it then follows that $\phi(\mathbf{w}_0) \in P_X$ iff $\neg\mathbf{w}_0 \in P_X$, and from there my argumentation in points 3 and 4 goes through?

@JulianNewman Yes, to the second comment. To the first, that is not true. There is generally a way to get from a proof of $w$ to a proof of $\phi(w)$ given sufficient power, but you can also have too much power sometimes and prove $\phi(w)$ even when there is no proof of $w$ (while not having too too much power and being inconsistent). Soundness means not having too much power in this sense.

@JulianNewman  In fact, just assuming $\lnot w_0$ (which is consistent assuming the original system is since it can't prove $w_0$) gets you into this state. By the equivalence in 2, assuming $\lnot w_0$ means you can prove that $w_0$ is provable (also in the new system since it's an extension of the original one)... but it's not since the system is still consistent and proves $\lnot w_0.$

Very clever example, thanks :)
